# resizable handler moves after overlay pop up div is scrolled down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm under this situation... i've made an overlay div working as a popup window.
Contains a little header that has some text and a "X" button to "close" it (which is a child div). Then it has the body content as another child div.

I've set the draggable and re-sizable jquery functionality to the parent overlay popup window.
Works fine... sort of speak, because when i scroll down due to large content, the little handler resize icon moves up or down depending on how I scroll instead of being fixed at the bottom like where it was in the first place.

And another thing, the little child divs inside its parent aren't resized with the parent's size. How can i achieve that?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="sendmessage-panel-overlay">
    <div id="overlay-header">
        <h1 id="title" style="font-size: 12px; float: left; padding-top: 7px;"></h1>
        <div id="maximize_icon">
            <img src="<c:url value='/images/x-icon.gif'/>" title="Close window" onclick="closePopUp()">
        </div>              
    </div>
    <div id="body-content"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#sendmessage-panel-overlay
{
    background-color: white;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    left: 21%;
    padding: 0px 17px 17px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 10%;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#overlay-header
{
   width: 700px; 
   position: fixed; 
   height: 30px; 
   background-color: #fff; 
}

#maximize_icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    float: right;
}

#body-content {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move the element outside of the scroll-able element or use `position: absolute` (probably combined with a `position: relative` somewhere).